# Displaying total at the top of stacked bar with indicator

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to show the total at the top of the stacked bar graph. But it is showing very far from the top of bar graph. sorry this might be duplicate question. [image]. Could anyone help me with adding indicator like one in the picture and showing the value at the top of the triangle? TIA

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve my problem. I added second series that is total of other 2 series and change the chart series type line with markers,gave the color 'No color',hide the legend  property and set the label position as top[image].But I do not know why the value shows below for the first column. this same technique I tried before I am posting my question.But it did not work at that time.Now it works except one value shows below the marker.
Reference:http://sqljason.com/2010/06/display-total-on-top-of-stacked-chart_8589.html